# dynamic function call on afterwards added html-element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i try to replace a given user link in a p-tag text with an a-tag. is it possible to dynamically call a function with a given number variable?

```
let ul = "@someUserLink"
let ulId = 3294234;

let replace = "<a onclick='{ this.callFucntionWithGivenId(ulId) }' style='color: orangered;'>" + ul.userLink + "</a>";
this.message.message = this.message.message.replace(ul.userLink, replace);
```

Comment: How is that related to angular and TypeScript?

Comment: the app is written in typescript. is use angular and maybe there a special features in angular that i don't know.